# jquery password123 mask plugin elem is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am getting this error from password123 plugin, although not sure what could be causing because its worked fine on a previous project. Maybe a newer version of jquery.

It works fine when there is a input password field in the page although shows the below error then there isn't. How can I fix this?

> Error: TypeError: elem is undefined Source File:
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js Line: 1719
>   `var noData = elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[
>   elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()`

Block:

```
// A method for determining if a DOM node can handle the data expando
    acceptData: function( elem ) {
        var noData = elem.nodeName && jQuery.noData[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];

        // nodes accept data unless otherwise specified; rejection can be conditional
        return !noData || noData !== true && elem.getAttribute("classid") === noData;
    }
```

Doc ready:

```
$('input:password').password123({
    character: "&#9679;"
});
```

Full Plugin:

```
/**
*   @preserve jQuery password123: iPhone Style Passwords Plugin - v1.5 - 2/1/2011
*   http://timmywillison.com/samples/password123/
*   Copyright (c) 2011 timmy willison
*   Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licences.
*   http://timmywillison.com/licence/
*/

// *Version: 1.5, Last updated: 2/1/2011*
//
// Demo         - http://timmywillison.com/samples/password123/
// Testing      - http://timmywillison.com/samples/password123/qunit/test/
// GitHub       - http://github.com/timmywil/password123
// Source       - http://github.com/timmywil/password123/raw/master/jquery.password123.js (13.8kb)
// (Minified)   - http://github.com/timmywil/password123/raw/master/jquery.password123.min.js (5.2kb)
//
// License
//
// Copyright (c) 2011 timmy willison,
// Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
// http://timmywillison.com/licence/
//
// Support and Testing
//
// Versions of jQuery and browsers this was tested on.
//
// jQuery Versions - 1.3.2-1.5
// Browsers Tested - Internet Explorer 6-8, Firefox 2-3.7, Safari 3-5,
//                   Chrome 4-6, Opera 9.6-10.5.
//
// Release History
//
// 1.5   - (2/1/2011) Added widget-style option method, only instantiate when not calling a method
// 1.4   - (2/1/2011) Restructured plugin, added destroy method, added tests
// 1.3   - (11/23/2010) Added Google Closure Compiler comments, common password field attribute
//              support when replacing fields, and no longer sends placeholder value when submitting the form.
// 1.2   - (9/28/2010) Placeholders changed to only work with HTML5 placeholder attribute,
//              'value' attribute now reserved for actual values
// 1.1   - (7/5/2010) Add Placeholder functionality
// 1.0   - (7/4/2010) Initial release
//
// See README for usage and placeholder explanation

;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    // Extend jQuery
    $.fn.password123 = function ( options ) {
        var instance = $.data( this[0], "password123" ),
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        // Catch method calls
        if ( !!instance && typeof options === "string" && options.charAt( 0 ) !== "_" && instance[ options ] ) {
            args.unshift( this );
            return instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );
        }

        return this.map(function( i, elem ) {
            // Returns the new password fields for chaining
            // Old password fields are removed
            return new password123._init( elem, options );
        });
    };

    var clear_timeout = window.clearTimeout,
        counter = 0,
    password123 = {

        _init: function( elem, options ) {

            // Catch fields that aren't password fields
            if ( !elem.type === "password" ) {
                return elem;
            }

            var self = this;

            // Continue regularly
            self.options = $.extend({

                // You can use any html character code or
                // plain text character
                character: "&#8226;",

                // This is the delay(ms) for when the last
                // character will change
                delay: 2000,

                // Use any prefix you like for the new
                // field ids, but they will always be zero-indexed
                prefix: "iField",

                // Enable the override of the placeholder attribute
                placeholder: true,

                // With this classname, you can set placeholder
                // specific styles in your own css
                placeholderClass: 'input_placeholder',

                // When true, this will mask the placeholder or initial value
                maskInitial: false
            }, options);

            // HTML encode the character
            self.encodedChar = $('<div>'+ self.options.character +'</div>').text();

            // Replace the fields with what we need
            // and store in var fields
            self.$field = self._replaceField( elem )

                // Bind textchange to the fields with
                // the letterChange function
                .bind('textchange', function() {
                    self._letterChange.call( self );
                });


            // Add placeholder stuff
            if ( self.options.placeholder ) {
                self._bindPlaceholder();
            }

            // Mask the placeholder or initial value if needed
            if ( self.options.maskInitial ) {
                self.$field.keyup();
            }

            // Return the new password field
            return self.$field[0];
        },

        /**
         * Replaces the password field with a hidden field
         * and adds the new visible text field.
         * @param {object} $field One field to replace
         * @return {object} The new text field.
         * @private
         */
        _replaceField: function( field ) {
            var self     = this,
                $field   = $(field),
                place    = $field.attr('placeholder') || undefined,
                field_id = self.options.prefix + counter++,
                value    = $field.val() || ( self.options.placeholder ? place || '' : '' ),
                classes  = self.options.placeholder && place !== undefined && (value === place || value === '') ?
                                field.className + ' ' + self.options.placeholderClass :
                                field.className,
                attrs = { 'class': classes, 'id': field_id, 'value': value, 'placeholder': self.options.placeholder ? undefined : place },
                standards = [ 'size', 'tabindex', 'readonly', 'disabled', 'maxlength' ];

            // Combine attrs with standard attrs
            for ( var i = 0; i < standards.length; i++ ) {
                var attr = $field.attr( standards[i] );
                attrs[ standards[i] ] = attr && attr > -1 ? attr : undefined;
            }

            // The hidden field that will get sent with the form
            self.$hidden = $('<input type="hidden"/>')
                .attr({
                    'name': $field.attr('name'),
                    'id': field.id,
                    'class': field.className,
                    'disabled': $field.attr('disabled')
                })
                .replaceAll( $field )
                .val( value !== place ? value : '' );

            self.$oldField = $field;

            // The main field
            return $('<input type="text"/>')
                .attr( attrs )
                .insertAfter( self.$hidden )
                .data({
                    'value': $field.val() || '', // If value was set, fill it in correctly
                    'placeholder': place, // Attach placeholder for comparison to value
                    'newVal': value, // This to avoid sending the placeholder value when submitting the form
                    'password123': self // Attach the instance of this plugin
                });
        },

        /**
         * Calls for the necessary adjustments when
         * a field is changed
         * @private
         */
        _letterChange: function( elem ) {
            var fv = this.$field.val();

            if ( fv.length > this.$field.data('value').length ) {

                // Apply fieldChange as normal
                this.$field.data( 'value', this._fieldChange() );

            } else if ( fv.length < this.$field.data('value').length ) {

                // Clear the timeout for the last character
                clear_timeout( this.last );

                var old = this.$hidden.val(),
                    newVal;

                if ( fv.length < old.length - 1 ) {
                    newVal = old.substr( 0, fv.length );
                } else {
                    var cp = this._getCursorPosition();

                    // Create the new value with the correct
                    // character deleted
                    newVal = old.length > cp + 1 && cp > -1
                        ? old.slice(0, cp).concat(old.slice(cp + 1))
                        : old.slice(0, cp);
                }

                // Update data and the hidden input
                this.$field.data({ 'value': fv, 'newVal': newVal });
                if ( newVal !== this.$field.data('placeholder') ) {
                    this.$hidden.val( newVal );
                }
            }

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Updates the field with the dots as the user types,
         * and sets the timeout for the last char.
         * @return {string} The new value to set to field.data
         * @private
         */
        _fieldChange: function() {
            var self = this;

            // Clear the timeout for the last character
            clear_timeout( self.last );
            var fv = self.$field.val(), len = fv.length,
                old = self.$hidden.val(),
                cp = self._getCursorPosition(),
                newVal;

            // Update the hidden value with the correct value
            // depending on cursor position
            newVal = old.length > cp + 1 && cp > -1
                ? old.substr(0, cp-1) + fv.charAt(cp-1) + old.substr(cp-1)
                : old + fv.charAt(len - 1);
            self.$field.data('newVal', newVal);
            if ( newVal !== self.$field.data('placeholder') ) {
                self.$hidden.val( newVal );
            }

            if ( len > 1 ) {

                // Loop through and change all characters
                for ( var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++ ) {
                    fv = fv.replace( fv.charAt(i), self.encodedChar );
                }

                // Update the field
                self.$field.val( fv );
            }
            if ( len > 0 ) {

                // Set the timeout for the last character
                self.last = setTimeout(function () {
                    cp = self._getCursorPosition();
                    fv = self.$field.val();
                    fv = fv.replace( fv.charAt(len - 1), self.encodedChar );
                    self.$field.val( fv ).data('value', fv);

                    // Reset cursor position to what it was if not at end
                    if ( cp != len ) {
                        self._setCursorPosition( cp );
                    }
                }, self.options.delay);
            }

            // Reset cursor position to what it was if not at end
            if ( cp != len ) {
                self._setCursorPosition( cp );
            }
            return fv;
        },

        /**
         * Placeholder functionality
         * @private
         */
        _bindPlaceholder: function() {
            var self = this,
                place = self.$field.data('placeholder');

            if ( place !== undefined ) {
                self.$field.bind({
                    "focus.password123": function() {
                        // Compare the hidden value with the placeholder value
                        if ( self.$field.data('newVal') === place ) {
                            self.$field.val('').removeClass( self.options.placeholderClass ).data( 'newVal', '' );
                            self.$hidden.val('');
                        }
                    },
                    "blur.password123": function() {
                        // If it's empty, put the placeholder in as the value
                        if ( place !== undefined && self.$field.val() === '' ) {
                            self.$field.val( place ).addClass( self.options.placeholderClass ).data( 'newVal', place );

                            // Mask the placeholder if needed
                            if ( self.options.maskInitial ) {
                                self.$field.keyup();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                self.$field.keyup();
            }
            return self;
        },

        /**
         * Remove placeholder functionality
         * @private
         */
        _changePlaceholder: function( isPlace ) {
            if ( isPlace && !this.options.placeholder ) {
                return this._bindPlaceholder();
            } else if ( !isPlace && this.options.placeholder ) {
                this.$field.focus().unbind('.password123').blur();
            }
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Change the id prefix on this field
         * @private
         */
        _changePrefix: function( value ) {
            var cur = this.$field.attr("id"),
                prev = this.options.prefix;
            this.$field.attr( 'id', cur.replace( prev, value ) );
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Gets the current cursor position in a textfield
         * to determine where to delete/update a character.
         * @return {Number} The index for the position of the cursor.
         * @private
         */
        _getCursorPosition: function() {
            var elem = this.$field[0];
            if ( elem != null ) {
                // IE
                if ( document.selection ) {
                    elem.focus();
                    var sel = document.selection.createRange();
                    sel.moveStart( 'character', -elem.value.length );
                    return sel.text.length;
                }
                // Others
                else if ( elem.selectionStart !== undefined ) {
                    return elem.selectionStart;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        },

        /**
         * Sets the cursor position to a previous state
         * if the field was updated somewhere in the middle.
         * @param {Element} field The raw field.
         * @param {Number} pos The position to set to.
         * @private
         */
        _setCursorPosition: function( pos ) {
            var elem = this.$field[0];
            if ( elem != null ) {
                // IE
                if ( elem.createTextRange ) {
                    var range = elem.createTextRange();
                    range.move('character', pos);
                    range.select();
                }
                // Others
                else if ( elem.setSelectionRange ) {
                    elem.focus();
                    elem.setSelectionRange( pos, pos );
                }
                else {
                    elem.focus();
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Internally sets options
         * @return password123 instance
         * @private
         */
        _setOptions: function( options ) {
            var self = this;
            $.each( options, function( key, value ) {
                switch ( key ) {
                    case "placeholder":
                        self._changePlaceholder( value === "false" ? false : value );
                        break;
                    case "prefix":
                        self._changePrefix( value );
                }
                self.options[ key ] = value;
            });
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Destroys everything password123 has done and
         * sets the original password field back in place
         * @return The original password field
         */
        destroy: function( elem ) {
            var val = this.$hidden.remove().val();
            return this.$oldField.val( val ).replaceAll( elem );
        },

        /**
         * Get/set option on an existing password123 instance
         * @return The password123 field
         */
        option: function( elems, key, value ) {
            if ( !key ) {
                return $.extend( {}, this.options ); // Avoids returning direct reference
            }
            var options = key;

            if ( typeof key === "string" ) {
                if ( value === undefined ) {
                    return this.options[ key ];
                }
                options = {};
                options[ key ] = value;
            }

            this._setOptions( options );

            return elems;
        }
    };
    password123._init.prototype = password123;

    // Textchange event with a little extra
    $.event.special.textchange = {
        setup: function( data, namespaces ) {
            $(this).bind('keyup.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.handler);
            $(this).bind('cut.textchange paste.textchange input.textchange', $.event.special.textchange.delayedHandler);
        },
        teardown: function( namespaces ) {
            $(this).unbind('.textchange');
        },
        handler: function( event ) {
            $.event.special.textchange.triggerIfChanged( $(this) );
        },
        delayedHandler: function( event ) {
            var $element = $(this);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $.event.special.textchange.triggerIfChanged( $element );
            }, 25);
        },
        triggerIfChanged: function( $element ) {
            var v = $element.val();

            if ( $element.val() !== $element.data('lastValue') ) {

                // Check if something larger than one letter was pasted into the field
                var p123 = $.data( $element[0], "password123" );
                if ( v.length > 1 && v.indexOf( p123.encodedChar ) === -1 ) {

                    // If so, we need to save it before it disappears,
                    // but continue with triggering the field change
                    // by taking the last letter off
                    v = v.substr(0, v.length-1);
                    $element.data('value', v);
                    p123.$hidden.val( v );
                }
                $element.trigger( 'textchange', $element.data('lastValue') );
                $element.data('lastValue', $element.val());
            }
        }
    };

})(jQuery, this, this.document);
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pzeYZ/

Comment: Instead of `$('input:password')` have you tried `$('input[type=password]')`?

Comment: Same error, thanks had not tired that